# Sidebar toggle in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, toggle, hide, show, sidebar

I have a problem with my code I'm using JSF and I created a header and a sidebar with bootstrap but the problem is I can't hide and show the sidebar with the menu-toggle icon (it's a commandLink with the id #menu-toggle).

and this the code of the sidebar :

```
 <div class="nav-side-menu">
    <div class="brand">Options</div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>

    <div class="menu-list">

        <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">


            <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" class="collapsed active">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> Inscription <span class="arrow"></span></a>
            </li>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products">
                <li><a href="#">Comptes étudiants</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Etudiants</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bacheliers (OPI)</a></li>
            </ul>


            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#service" class="collapsed">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i> Paramétrage <span class="arrow"></span></a>
            </li>  
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="service">
                <li>add here</li>
            </ul>


            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#new" class="collapsed">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car fa-lg"></i> Utilisateurs </a>
            </li>



            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Statistiques
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> Historique
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wish that someone can answer me and thanks in advance.

Comment: No i'm developing a java 2ee application with JavaServer faces framework.. and in the header i have a icon i want to click and toggle the sidebar ..

Comment: Like this way you need https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/mhsatsqu/1/

Comment: thanks but the code you give me works if you minimized the page then the icon showed up and hide/show the div ...

Comment: It is a responsive nav bar..